# Django 1.1 vs Django 2.2

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django, just made a simple blogging website and now I want to move in more complex projects. I recently find [Django 1.11 ecommerce website tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzI3B-8ps2c&list=PLV2_Iivd4jxYVDWCcxmccusNaUx2kWCg1) which seems to be very nice, but I am concerned about its version. I need your advice at should I go with Django 1.1 here? how different are these two versions and what are some major changes to notice while following these tutorials?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Django 1.1 was released in 2009! That's 10 years ago, and is no longer supported (for a very long time). You will need to do all the changes specified in the release notes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/

Comment: Do you mean Django 1.11?  Your link points to a YouTube video that is about Django 1.11.  If so, then that is dramatically different from Django 1.1.  Django 1.1 is not even a thing anymore, whereas Django 1.11 is pretty similar to Django 2.2.  Just follow the tutorial, create the site, test it, and fix what breaks.  Never start a new project using old software - that will just lead to more time wasted down the line.

Comment: Thank you dear Willem Van Onsem

Comment: I just correct that mistake! it is Django 1.11 @kloddant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must mean django 1.11, not 1.1, because 1.1 is super old and unsupported.

In short, the most obvious differences between 1.11 and 2.2 is:

1. `url()` becomes `path()`, which makes it look a lot cleaner because
   regular expressions aren't visible in the url. They're still there,
   but they're far easier to write with the newer [path converters.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)
   But you can still use regex's if needed.
2. Python 3 only.
3. The locations of certain built in libraries have also changed a little bit.

Check the [release notes for 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/) as well.

Comment: ohhh my bad that is Django 1.11 so you mean I can follow that tutorial and it is not that different than Django 2.2

Comment: Correct. They're both very similar. So learning one over the other isn't a bad idea, because both are in use. 1.11 is used more right now, but 2.2 is the future, and easier to work with for the reasons stated above. My advice for a noob would be to start on 2.2 because it's easier due to the lack of regex's in the url's *(having extra things to learn can be aggravating)*. After that, learn regex's, and you'll be set.

Comment: No problem, and I forgot to say that here's a [free django 2.2 tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oQvMHpKkms). He has a 2.0 one I think too, as well as every version since 1.8 I think. Check his playlists. He has more in depth stuff on udemy too.